# How to create a check constraint that ensures one active detail record for a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

Let's say I have this as a table:

```
InvoiceDetailId  (int, not null, PK),
InvoiceId        (int, not null, FK),
InvoiceNumber    (varchar(50), null),
EndEffectiveTime (datetime, null)
```

How can I write a check constraint on this table that makes sure that for each invoice in the table there is only one record with a null EndEffectiveTime (meaning it's the active detail record)?

So basically this query can **never** return results:

```
SELECT   InvoiceId
FROM     InvoiceDetails
GROUP BY InvoiceId, EndEffectiveTime
HAVING   (EndEffectiveTime IS NULL)
         AND (COUNT(InvoiceDetailId) <> 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a unique filtered index.

```
create unique index UX_InvoiceDetails_InvoiceId on InvoiceDetails(InvoiceID) 
  where EndEffectiveTime is null
```

[Create Unique Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187019.aspx)
[Create Filtered Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/128c0/1)