# How to create a constraint on the below validation for the Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

How to create a constraint on the below validation for the Table
Below query should always return Zero rows.

```
select Col1,Col2,count(*) from Table
  where Col2=1
group by Col1,Col2
having count(*)>1
```

For Better understanding I am giving data also

1. column 2 Value should have only 1 or 0 values
2. Column2 Value should always be 1 for each Column1 value and may have many 0

   ```
   Column1 Column2     
   1       1       
   1       0       
   1       0       
   1       1   X   This is wrong. Reason: This combination should be unique (1,1)
   2       1       
   2       1   X   This is wrong. Reason: This combination should be unique (2,1)
   2       0       
   3       1       
   3       1   X   This is wrong. Reason: This combination should be unique (3,1)
   3       0
   ```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: So, if `Col2` were named, say `default`, you're saying that each unique value in `Col1` should only be allowed one row marked as default? (Are the names *really* such a secret?)

Comment: If so, this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944288/how-to-create-a-check-constraint-that-ensures-one-active-detail-record-for-a-tab?rq=1) should point the way.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
create function f1()
returns int
begin
return(select 0  from Table1
  where Col2=1
group by Col1,Col2
having count(*)>1)

end
create table table1(Col1 int, Col2 int)
alter table table1 WITH NOCHECK add constraint ck_table1 check(dbo.f1()>0)
```